# Pay to two Paypal Account Through Single PHP Transaction

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal in the website. I know how to integrate it. I have the Script with me and its working fine. But I have a small problem. I want to have two transaction through single transaction:

Like I have a Service Provider, One is website owner and other is Customer. If customer Pays a $100 from Paypal. Then My Service Provider will get $95 and Website Owner will be getting $5. Is it possible?

I have the script that can pay $100 to only one person.

I am using the Wordpress CMS.

I created the following form:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" id="paypal_form" name="paypal_form" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="_xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="utf-8" name="charset">
<input type="hidden" value="nikg510@gmail.com" name="business">
<input type="hidden" value="return-url" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="cancel-url" name="cancel_return">
<input type="hidden" value="notify-url" name="notify_url">
<input type="hidden" value="Booking for 'Birth Part 3'" name="item_name">
<input type="hidden" value="25" name="item_number">
<input type="hidden" value="EUR" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="20" name="amount">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
<input type="submit" value="Pay via Paypal">
</form>
```

I encrypted the URL's for Security Reasons. With This I can pay to only one Person. Not to the Two.

Regards

Comment: you need to pay all money through to a single party first and then do a secondary transaction from your account to the other recipient.  you can't pay 2 people off one transaction

Comment: have u checked about mass payment option[personally i have not implemented yet]

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But was not so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Adaptive paypal api. You can go through this link
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/ or here is the good plugin for Adaptive paypal

https://easydigitaldownloads.com/extension/paypal-adaptive-payments/